# git repository and Visual Studio Code

Tags: git

In VSC, I have over 5000 Source Control untracked changes.  I don't understand how these 'changes' got into my VSC interface because I only cloned in one directory.  I want to remove them but will 'discard all changes' actually remove the files from my computer?

Comment: We need more information here.  Did you just do a Git clone?  It sounds like every file in the repo is being reported as modified.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming issues only ..

Comment: Look like a end of line problem where initial developer don't have the same OS and/or git settings

Answer (score 0):

Try to clone again after typing:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

That will avoid any automatic eol (end of line) transformation.
Then check in your IDE is the issue persists.